# Ubuntu hangs at the '_' prompt for 15' when booting. Do I need another driver for my Intel G31/G33 integrated graphics?

Tags: boot, intel-graphics

I have an ASROCK which uses Intel G31 graphics. Ubuntu says my graphics chipset is G33. Should I look for another driver or are they from the same family?

I am also having problems booting and that purple screen stuck so for this I asked this question. I have partially fixed the purple screen stuck by enabling (uncommenting) this line in grub:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

But Ubuntu still hangs at start up for about 15 minutes  with a black screen and only the '_' prompt.

Here is a link for an overview of my [**ASROCK G31M-S**](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=G31M-S)

Answer (score 0):

> *I have an [**ASROCK G31M-S**](http://www.asrock.com/mb/overview.asp?Model=G31M-S) which uses Intel G31 graphics.
>   Ubuntu says my graphics chipset is G33.*

If the link you provided is for your motherboard then you have an Intel G31. I am not sure what you mean when you say Ubuntu says your graphics chipset is a G33. If Ubuntu does "*say*" this, then it is slightly confused.

If you look at the entries for the G31 & G33 chipsets in this [table on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_G33#Core_2_chipsets), you can see that they are very similar. The primary difference between them is that the G31 uses the ICH7 southbridge and only supports 4 GB of RAM. The G33 uses an ICH9, can support 8 GB of RAM, and also can support DDR3 RAM.

In particular, both the G31 & G33 provide the same integrated graphics: Intel GMA 3100. In other words, there is no difference between the G31 & the G33 in terms of the type of graphics supported.

---

If the hang at the `_` prompt occurs **after** the GRUB boot menu (or if you do not see a GRUB boot menu), then you might see if using the `nomodeset` kernel boot option helps.

#### Adding the `nomodeset` kernel option for a single boot

You can edit the boot instructions for the GRUB menu entry to add the `nomodeset` option to see if it corrects your graphics problem.

1. Boot to the GRUB boot menu. An example of the menu is shown in the screenshot below.

   [image: screenshot showing an example of the GRUB boot menu]

   **Note:** If you do **not** see the GRUB boot menu when you boot, try pressing and holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key immediately after the BIOS portion of the boot completes.
2. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry for the Ubuntu kernel you wish to boot.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the GRUB boot commands for the selected boot menu entry.
4. Look near the bottom of the list of commands for lines similar to

   `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=bc6f8146-1523-46a6-8b\`

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash`

   `initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic`
5. Change the middle line in (4) by adding the kernel boot parameter `nomodeset` to the end of the line (i.e. after `ro  quiet splash`).

   For this example you would change

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash` 

   to 

   `6a-64b819ccf2b7 ro  quiet splash nomodeset`
6. ***Without*** leaving this GRUB edit screen, press either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot using the modified kernel options.

**Note:** These changes are **not** persistent. Any change to the kernel boot options made this way will only affect the next boot and only if you start that boot by pressing either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> while still in GRUB edit mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, I tried 'nomodeset' but it make the screen shaking so I guess it's not fit with my graphic chipset am also see GRUB menu every time I boot my PC and the _ prompt occur happen after the GRUB menu.

Comment: I also added line after quiet splash that's I was should mention it earlier because am uncommented GRUB_TERMINAL=console it showed me after the grub menu "no video card detected" so I fixed that by adding "rootdelay=90". am also use 'GRUB coustomizer' app to do these stuff because it's GUI :)

Comment: @Doctoa Was the error you were seeing `no video card detected` or `no video mode activated`? If it was the latter, this is not a serious error and does not need to be corrected. (And if it was the former, then how were you able to see the error message without a video card?)

Comment: wel it's 90 not 900. and when I change it to 5 it's now bring me the 'Busybox (initramfs)' method so I change it back to 90 and it's ok as past.

Comment: `I am not sure what you mean when you say Ubuntu says your graphics chipset is a G33. If Ubuntu does "say" this, then it is slightly confused` Ubuntu show it on `system information` under `Graphics chipset` tap!